# how to sniff packets using built-in .Net functionality

Tags: c#, network-programming, packet-sniffers

I want to sniff the arrival packets on a specific port for basic header checks (mainly source IP and the flags). It is easy to achieve by using winpcap. 
Also one can use Network monitor as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953575/how-to-sniff-local-outgoing-network-traffic-in-net-without-using-pcap). Network monitor is also bulky and installs the drivers which makes my setup a two step process. I wondered if there is a way to do same using pure .net?

I didn't find  promiscuous mode socket listeners, 
however using:

```
IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().GetActiveTcpConnections()
```

I can get all active connections and their flags. The only issues is that I did not find an event to bind my listener to. All I can do is to put the above code inside a loop and check which is not what I want:

```
while (true)
{
Connections = GetIPGlobalProperties().GetActiveTcpConnections().Where(c => c.LocalEndPoint.Port == xxx && c.State == TcpState.SynReceived);
//Do some operation on Connections
}
```

Any ideas or is there a way to bind a listener?

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://www.drowningintechnicaldebt.com/RoyAshbrook/archive/2013/02/13/simple-sniffer-in-c.aspx)? Not related to your approach, but tells you how to do promiscuous sockets.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like the direction I missed to find. I would mark as answer if you'd like to post it. Might be helpful to others too.